# Объявление переменных POST запроса

Tags: php

При запросах серверу `xhr.send("info-edit&user=1&content=html")`

**info-edit:**
**user:** 1
**content:** html

Решил избавиться от кода такого типа:

```
if(isset($_POST['info-edit'])) {
    $user = (int) $_POST['user'];
    $content = (string) $_POST['content'];
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Чтобы объявить в одну строку все переменные
2. Проверить запрос на все ключи
3. Не писать каждый раз такие штуки как `$_POST` и `isset`
4. Более аккуратный код

---

Создал функцию *request* для запуска скрипта по первому ключу из запроса.
Затем, сопоставляю ключи к объявляемым переменным в list по порядку. В случае отсутствия ключа возвращаю ошибку клиенту:

```
if(request('info-edit')) {
    list($id, $content) = post('user', 'content');
    echo 'user id is '.$id;
}
```

---

Код выше работает, но всё равно меня не устраивает.
Нельзя в списке задать тип переменной `list((int) $id)`
Искал аналог `list()` или написание функции с объявлением переменной в аргументе что-то вроде кода ниже, но ничего не нашёл

```
post((int) $id, 'id');
echo $id;

function post($var, $key) {
    return $var = $_POST[$key];
}
```

---

Пока остался на решении проверять ключи и по ним же создавать глобально переменные, но тип переменных не объявлен

```
if(request('info-edit')) {
    post('user', 'content');
    echo $user.', '.$content;
}

function post() {
    foreach(func_get_args() as $key) {
        if(isset($_POST[$key])) {
            $GLOBALS[$key] = $_POST[$key];
        } else {
            echo 'err: bad request';
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Как лучше проверить запрос заданный на сервере в начале скрипта в одну строчку с объявлением переменных и их типом?
Или как передать в функцию post тип `(int)` или `(string)` по умолчанию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пришёл к более лучшему варианту

<sup>xhr: `info=`&`int=69`&`bool=1`&`string=text`</sup>

```
if(request('info')) {

    list($int, $bool, $string) = array(
        (int) post('int'),
        (bool) post('bool'),
        (string) post('string')
    );

    echo gettype($int).' '.$int.'; ';
    echo gettype($bool).' '.($bool ? 'true' : 'false').'; ';
    echo gettype($string).' '.$string.'; ';
}
```

<sub>log: `integer 69;` `boolean true;` `string text;`</sub>

Если нет необходимости в создании листа

```
if(request('info')) {
    $id = (int) post('int');
}
```

---

```php
function request($key) {
    return key($_POST) == $key ? true : false;
}

function post($key) {
    if(isset($_POST[$key])) {
        return $_POST[$key];
    } else {
        echo 'err: bad request'; exit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

POST-данные передаются через строку, поэтому тип данных не сохраняется. В суперглобальном массиве `$_POST` у вас будет только два типа - строка и массив.

Один из вариантов, использовал префикс в именах параметров

```
i_id=532&s_name=hellen
```

Можно создать функцию `type_cast()`, которая будет разбивать ключ по символу _ и в зависимости от префикса приводить к тому или иному типу

```
<?php
if(request('info-edit')) {
    post('i_user', 's_content');
    echo $user.', '.$content;
}

function type_cast($key, $value) {
  list($prefix) = explode('_', $key);
  switch($prefix) {
    case 'i':
      $value = (int)$value;
      break;
    case 's'
      $value = (string)$value;
      break;
    default:
      $value = (string)$value;
  }
}

function post() {
    foreach(func_get_args() as $key) {
        if(isset($_POST[$key])) {
            $GLOBALS[$key] = type_cast($key, $_POST[$key]);
        } else {
            echo 'err: bad request';
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В самом запросе недопустимо объявлять тип, а на серверной части вполне как вариант использовать префикс. Сам что-то не додумался, позже попробую :)

Comment: Плюснул, но сделал свой велосипед :D